# Netcat on remote machine using ssh

Tags: c++, c, ssh, netcat

I was trying to run netcat by using ssh and seems that my code always fails in my C code. Here are the commands which I am executing using system() in this order.

```
system("ssh machine 'nc -l 61001|dd bs=64M of=temp' &")
system("/bin/dd if=filename bs=64M|nc IP_address 61001")
```

I noticed that the first command works correctly as the temp file is created on the remote machine. The second dd command fails and states that 0 bytes has been written on the remote machine. These commands work correctly when executed from the terminal, but fail as soon as I put it in system() calls in C.

Comment: Try using the full path to `filename`.  The way the code is written is that it assumes `filename` is in the current directory.

Comment: filename is an alias, I am passing the fullpath

Comment: `&` (run in background) does not work for `system`. The shell is terminated between each call and all subprocesses with it.

Comment: So is it possible to run two commands in one system call?

Comment: @StenSoft - Would a `nohup` fix that?

Comment: @Mr.Llama Maybe, you would need to check it. But I would not recommend it, it won't close the netcat when `dd` is done.

Comment: @chettyharish Yes, with a semicolon, just like in a shell

Comment: Tried that, If I use '&' followed by ';' , it states -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'  . If I run it without the '&' , then I am stuck at the nc command itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short answer:

a `& disown` (instead of just &) should do.

#### Explanation:

`system()` spawns a shell that just executes *one* command and then exits. The `&` tells the shell to fork the command into background (means, it doesn't wait for its completion), but it's still part of the session and process group of the shell. When the group leader (the shell) exits, all children are killed. The `disown` causes the shell to start new process group, the child process is now *owned* by `init` (the first process in the system).

#### "Real" answer:

This is about programming. You are forking processes like crazy to accomplish something a C program could easily do using builtin library calls (except for the `ssh` but there are better ways, too). Go read on *BSD sockets*.

Comment: disown disowns the main process too (even inside forked process) thus the main process is stopped.

Comment: uhm, no. try this: `int main() { system("bash -c 'gimp &disown'"); }` to verify (added explicit `bash` because on my system, `/bin/sh` is `dash` that doesn't know about `disown` but disowns by default).

Comment: If I do something like system("/bin/bash ssh machine 'nc -l 61001|dd bs=64M of=temp ' & disown") , it still fails stating that /usr/bin/ssh: cannot execute binary file ( I guess it doesnt recognize the command)

Comment: Using a -c causes the netcat to close first and then dd starts to write transferring 0 bytes